# Null reference exception While Navigating to PlayListItem

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am trying to play the selected media from PlayList,if the selected index is not zero as below:

```
if (playList.Items.Count == 0)
   {
      setPlayList();
          if (selectedIndex!= 0)
               { 
                  if(custMediaElement.Playlist!=null)
                  custMediaElement.GoToPlaylistItem(selectedIndex);
               }
    }
```

But I am getting a Null reference Exception while trying to go to PlayList Item with the help of selected index , as explained in top. This works fine if I don't use `custMediaElement.GoToPlaylistItem(selectedIndex);` but in that case the Media Player Always plays the 1st Item , No matter , Which ever Song I select from the List Box.

Below is few details from Stack Trace:

```
ExpressionMediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.DoOpenPlaylistItem(PlaylistItem playlistItem)
at ExpressionMediaPlayer.MediaPlayer.GoToPlaylistItem(Int32 playlistItemIndex)
```

Thanks,

Subhen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging through Got the method which worked :

```
 custMediaElement.GoToPlaylistItemOnNextTick(currentPlayListItem);
```