# What is the difference between GoToPlaylistItem and GoToPlaylistItemOnNextTick

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, playlist

Unable to understand the difference bettwen `GoToPlaylistItem` and `GoToPlaylistItemOnNextTick`, though `GoToPlaylistItemOnNextTick` clicked on scenarios where `GoToPlaylistItem` din't work.

If you wonder if there are any differences, Have a look at this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873359/null-reference-exception-while-navigating-to-playlistitem) for a problem solved by using `GoToPlaylistItemOnNextTick` while it was throwing null exception with `GoToPlaylistItem`

While I naviaged to the defination I got the following details. Could some one explain?

```
[ScriptableMember]
public virtual void GoToPlaylistItem(int playlistItemIndex);
public void GoToPlaylistItemOnNextTick(int playlistItemIndex);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MediaPlayer` uses a `Timer` internally. This timer is created in a protected method called `CreatePositionTimer`:

```
protected void CreatePositionTimer(TimeSpan interval)
{
    if (m_timer == null)
    {
        m_timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        m_timer.Interval = interval; // 6 NTSC frames
        m_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(OnTimerTick);
    }
}
```

The method `GoToPlaylistItemOnNextTick` simply sets a few internal variables:

```
public void GoToPlaylistItemOnNextTick(int playlistItemIndex)
{
    if (!m_goToItemOnNextTick) // don't set it if already set
    {
        m_goToItemOnNextTick = true;
        m_goToItemOnNextTickIndex = playlistItemIndex;
    }
}
```

The next time the timer comes around, `OnTimerTick` is called, and this checks for the above variables and then calls `GoToPlaylistItem`:

```
void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    [...]

    if (m_goToItemOnNextTick)
    {
        m_goToItemOnNextTick = false;
        GoToPlaylistItem(m_goToItemOnNextTickIndex);
    }

    [...]
}
```

So the difference is that `GoToPlaylistItem` will go to the next playlist item immediately, while `GoToPlaylistItemOnNextTick` will do it at the next timer tick. The specific timer it uses is `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`. This ensures that `GoToPlaylistItem` will be called when the UI thread is idle.

The difference may be significant if you rely on some of the events that `MediaPlayer` fires, for example `StateChanged`. If you call `GoToPlaylistItem`, this event will execute immediately before `GoToPlaylistItem` returns. If you call `GoToPlaylistItemOnNextTick`, then the event will only occur later when your current method has finished and the UI thread is idle.

Comment: Thanks . Good to know what this was happenin?But why GoToPlaylistItem sometimes gives a null reference error while GoToPlaylistItemOnNextTick works. Link to the [Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873359/null-reference-exception-while-navigating-to-playlistitem "Null reference exception While Navigating to PlayListItem.")

Comment: His code calls something called `setPlayList()` in the same method. Obviously I can’t know what it does, but if it tries to make changes to the playlist (which is likely), it may be the case that the MediaPlayer needs a chance to update the playlist first before it can jump to an item in it.